# what to include?

Tags: ros, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,i'm very new in ROS so sorry if my question is silly..

i've read the tutorials on ros,now i'm triyng to control the turtlesim to make a square (an exercise) so i'm doing:

```
#include <turtlesim/Pose.h>
#include <turtlesim/Velocity.h>
```

to use their topic,but when i make it it says that pose.h does not exist:what's the problem?

i'm in the beginner_tutorials package,maybe is that it doesn't find pose.h in this package?if so, how can i include pose.h from its package?
thanks all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29796/what-to-include?/) by [ldima](https://answers.ros.org/users/1979/ldima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ldima](https://answers.ros.org/users/1979/ldima/) on 2012-03-15**:
Thanks the both of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You also have to make sure that you add:

```
<depend package="turtlesim" />
```

to your package's `manifest.xml`.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-15**:
@DimitriProsser I removed the reference to geometry_msgs from this answer, there's a separate simpler Pose and Velocity for turtlesim

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-03-15**:
Ah, my mistake. Thanks for the correction.